# Adicionar e editar elemento AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

Boas,
Quero editar um `tr`depois de criá-lo e adĩcionado por AJAX.

1. Quando eu clico no criar 'Marca':

   ```
   $('#confirmCreateBrand').click(function(){
   brand = $('#createbrand_name').val();
   advertiser = $(this).attr('advertiser-id');
   user = $(this).attr('user-id');


   if(brand == ""){
     $('#createbrand_name').css('border','1px solid red');
     $('#createbrand_name_error').show();
     return false;
   }

    var brand = {
           advertiser_id: advertiser,
           name: brand,
           user : user,
           _token :"{{ csrf_token() }}",
         }; 

     $.ajax({
       url: '{{ URL::to('brand/store/') }}',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       data: brand,
       success: function(brand) {
       $('#brandsTable').find('tbody:last-child').append('<tr id="brand-'+brand.id+'"><td>'+brand.name+'</td><td> <button brand-id="'+brand.id+'" brand-name="'+brand.name+'" brand-advertiser="'+{{$advertiser->id}}+'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBrandModal" class="editBrandBtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button> <button brand-id="'+brand.id+'" brand-name="'+brand.name+'"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteBrandModal" class="deleteBrandBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button> </td></tr>');

           $('#createBrand').modal('hide');

         $('#createBrand input').val('');
       }
     });
   ```

   })
2. Esta função adiciona-me um `tr` com os botoes editar e apagar.
3. mas quando clico no editar num elemento depois de o adiciona, nao me entra nesta função.
   Se fizer refresh à página já entra.

   ```
   $('.editBrandBtn').click(function(){
   name = $(this).attr('brand-name');
   brand_id = $(this).attr('brand-id');
   alert(brand_id);
   $('#editbrand_name').val(name);
   $('#confirmEditBrand').attr('brand-id',brand_id);
   ```

   });

podem-me ajudar, sff?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Este é o site do stackoverflow em português, traduza sua pergunta ou faça a pergunta no site em inglês

Comment: Por favor em Português...

Comment: Traduzido, peço desculpa.

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi esta questão...

coloquei todo o meu JS dentro de:

```
$(document).bind('ready ajaxComplete', function(){
  //TodoJSdesteFicheiro
});
```

Como o elemento é adicionado depois do AJAX correr e as funções do Editar e Apagar só estavam disponiveis no document ready, é necessário fazer esta alteração antes do javascript, para que as funcções estejam disponiveis quando o DOM estiver 'pronto' e depois do 'AjaxComplete'.